# Coq auto-simplification similar to Isabelle?

Tags: coq, isabelle

In Isabelle, it's possible to mark facts (such as theorems) of the form P=Q with the "simp" attribute. Then when proving things, the "simp" and "auto" tactics will use such facts to convert occurrences of P to Q.

Does Coq have a similar mechanism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a look at the documentation about [auto](http://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual010.html#hevea_tactic141) and [autorewrite](http://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual010.html#hevea_tactic145), I think it is what you are looking for.

I know you can feed some hint database to `auto` (with `Hint Resolve` iirc) but I'm not sure you can do the same with `autorewrite`.

Comment: you can have your custom hint database with `autorewrite`: use `Hint Rewrite`.